# PHP/MySQL wait 30 seconds filter

Tags: php, mysql, timer

I'm not really sure how to go about this but basically I'm just trying to make a user wait 30 seconds before he can post again..

Here's my code and It's pretty self explanatory.

```
$plus30secs = time() + 30;

if($db->rows("SELECT null FROM comments WHERE userid = '1' AND time > " . $plus30secs . "") == 0) {
    $db->query("INSERT INTO comments (userid, content, time) VALUES ('1' ,'hi..' ,'" . time() . "')");
} else {
    echo 'wait atleast 30 seconds between posting.
}
```

Thank you for all help in advanced.

Comment: Whats wrong with your solution? :)

Comment: Just doesn't work the way it should.

Answer (score 0):

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['upd']=time();
?>
<form action="om.php" method="post">
</form>
```

**om.php**

```
session_start();
    if(time()-$_SESSION['upd']>30){
        //mysql_query();
        echo 'query run';
    }
```

You can also use javascript-timers to send the Ajax-request

Comment: Not really good, if a bot changes reset it's ssid, he can post way more than a post every 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You should always keep the poster's IP address.

Anyway, I think you should check with "minus30secs", instead of "plus30secs".

Answer (score 0):

Your select should never return a row unless someone would be able to time travel into the future and post a comment. 
I would modify the code like this:

```
$rows=$db->rows("SELECT time FROM comments WHERE userid = '1' order by time desc limit 1");
if(!count($rows) || $rows[1]['time'] + 30 < time()) {
    $db->query("INSERT INTO comments (userid, content, time) VALUES ('1' ,'hi..' ,'" . time() . "')");
} else {
    echo 'wait atleast 30 seconds between posting.'
}
```